# Python: Convert packet object/inet object to 32 bit integer

Tags: python, sockets

I have IPv4 address and want to convert it to 32 bit integer. 
i am able to convert IPv4 address into string using socket.inet_ntop and then convert that string to 32 bit integer
but is there a direct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An IPv4 address in its basic form *is* a 32-bit integer in network byte order. 
I'm assuming you have it as a sequence of bytes (because that is what you would normally hand off to `inet_ntop`).

What you will need to convert it into a python integer is the `struct` module and its `unpack` method along with the "!I" format specification (which means network byte order, unsigned 32-bit integer). See this code:

```
from socket import inet_ntop, inet_pton, AF_INET
from struct import unpack

ip = inet_pton(AF_INET, "192.168.1.42")
ip_as_integer = unpack("!I", ip)[0]
print("As string[{}] => As bytes[{}] => As integer[{}]".format(
      inet_ntop(AF_INET, ip), ip, ip_as_integer))
```

You could of course also reconstruct the integer bytewise:

```
ip_as_integer = (ip[0] << 24) | (ip[1] << 16) | (ip[2] << 8) | ip[3]
```